# prevent read/write to a variable at the same time in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a global variable in jquery. Two diffirent functions reading and modifying this variable in runtime.

One jquery function is reading value from this variable on every 2000 seconds and resettng it. And, a SignalR method updating this variable whenever it gets any update from server.

Is there any way to lock that variable to others while reading or writing to it?

Comment: javascript follows a single threaded execution(except workers) so there is no way there will be simultaneous modification of a variable

Comment: @Arun, if two functions attempt to change the variable at the same time?

Comment: javascript will not execute 2 functions at the same time.... it uses a queue system to queue executions where it will be executed one after another

Comment: @Arun, answer it so that i can accecp it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript follows a single threaded execution pattern(except web workers) so there is no way for simultaneous modification/read of a variable.

Also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded)

Comment: Just for completeness, web workers do not share data (everything is copied around), so locking is not necessary even in that case.